# How to convert Instant not stored in UTC to UTC?

Tags: java, time

I'm getting an Instant from DB1, that is supposed to be in UTC, and putting it in DB2. But the instant I'm getting is in DB1 local time. I have their timezone(ZoneId) but I can't figure out how to convert it to UTC before putting it in DB2

Comment: Can you show some examples of what you mean? An instant is never "in" anything. An instant is just a point in time. If the DB gives you a different point in time than the one you are expecting, then either the DB is broken, or you are not reading from it correctly.

Comment: So I'm looking in DB1 and I see the "created" column getting new data coming in that is being stored locally like `2022-01-03 10:29:54.567` When UTC time is `2022-01-03 16:29:54.567` So the DB is not storing in UTC. Now I have access to DB1 but I cannot change anything on it

Comment: That looks like a `LocalDateTime` to me, not an `Instant`.

Comment: Ahhhh. I think I'm converting `LocalDateTime` to `Instant` which is causing the issue. Thank you!

Comment: (a) No, you are not getting an `Instant` from your database. Not if using JDBC, which has no mapping for `Instant` class. (b) You need to provide much more detail when posting here. Your Question cannot be addressed properly as currently written. What version of what database with what JDBC driver are you using? What is the exact data type of your column? What exactly are your inputs, outputs, and expectations?

Answer (score 0):

An `Instant` is *always* in UTC, and *never* needs timezone conversion.  If you tried to convert an `Instant` to an `Instant` in another timezone correctly, you would always get exactly the same `Instant` back.

What you must have is a bug in how it's being stored, or how it's being displayed.

Comment: It's possible that the server's "UTC time" has been set to the local time (i.e. the configuration of the DB1 server is incorrect).

Comment: Yeah that's the problem I'm running into. I can't change any settings on DB1